# Why are CodeIgniter Active Record and phpMyAdmin giving different results?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, activerecord

```
SELECT accounts.NameSurname, Projects.Name, personnels.NameSurname 
FROM accounts 
JOIN projects ON ( accounts.Id = projects.AccountId ) 
JOIN projectpersonnels ON ( projects.Id = projectpersonnels.ProjectId ) 
JOIN accounts AS personnels ON ( projectpersonnels.AccountId = personnels.Id )
```

results in NameSurname Name NameSurname colums

---

Why would the queries above and below result in different "columns" titles and number of columns?
I am running the query above in phpmyadmin.
using mysql and codeigniter 1.7.3

---

```
$this->db->select('accounts.NameSurname,projects.Name,personnels.NameSurname');
$this->db->from('accounts');
$this->db->join('projects','accounts.Id = projects.AccountId' );
$this->db->join('projectpersonnels','projects.Id = projectpersonnels.ProjectId');
$this->db->join('accounts as personnels','projectpersonnels.AccountId = personnels.Id');
$q=$this->db->get();
```

results in: NameSurname (which is personnel) Name (which is project)

Thank you for reading and replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with how CI creates results.  You have a name collision.  Both of the `NameSurname`s are trying to be assigned to the same "key" in your object/array result.  Since `personnels.NameSurname` is second, it is overwriting the value of `accounts.NameSurname` (because it is being assigned to the same key).  If you were to use `accounts.NameSurname as aNameSurname` (not 100% sure if that is correct syntax for MySQL) instead of `accounts.NameSurname` that would likely make your results consistent.

This would actually cause the same problem with the PDO classes in certain circumstances too: `FETCH_ASSOC` and `FETCH_OBJ` would both only show two columns, but `FETCH_ARRAY` would show three.  `FETCH_BOTH` would result in there being three numeric indexes and two associative indexes.  (Not that you asked about PDO's, but I thought it might further illustrate the point).

Comment: cwalllenpolle thank you for your answer, 
$this->db->join('accounts','projectpersonnels.AccountId = personnels.Id',' AS personnels');

Comment: thank you but they are the same columns and I wanted the personnels to be alias of accounts. used'AS' to specify the alias as below:
$this->db->join('accounts as personnels','projectpersonnels.AccountId = personnels.Id');
I saw that  'LEFT' is supplied to activerecord join functions, tried code below:
$this->db->join('accounts','projectpersonnels.AccountId = personnels.Id','AS personnels'); didnt work also, its something to do with activerecord alias definitions?, how do we define aliases in activerecord.when I query by using sql syntax (db->query($sql)) as I defined alias, it doesnt work also